# How to send a polite and friendly reminder in a group chat?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request, idiomatic-language

I have to remind people in a group chat about deadlines. What are the best phrases to do this?

I tried to find a phrase but I could not except "please be reminded" and "a gentle reminder:". I'm not sure if these are correct and Idiomatic.

Comment: Just say whatever you've got to say. Prefacing it by ***anything*** that effectively means *Pay attention because I'm about to give you a reminder* will probably seem peremptory / rude to at least *some* of the people in the group. Especially if you're not their line manager.

Answer (score 1):

"Please be reminded" sounds very awkward to my native ear.  "Please" implies a request that they do something but "be reminded" is not something they do.  They already are just by reading what you wrote.

"Please remember" sounds much more natural to me

Google's Ngrams shows "please remember" being [significantly more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=26&year_end=2019&content=please%20remember%2C%20please%20be%20reminded&smoothing=3&year_start=1800&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cplease%20remember%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cplease%20be%20reminded%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cplease%20remember%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cplease%20be%20reminded%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 0):

> "please be reminded"

> "a gentle reminder"

These are clear, concise, and commonly accepted.  There is nothing wrong with them.